# issue with LRU cache of cachetools

Tags: python

i am using LRUCache from cachetools library, but when i am trying to append i am getting the error 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
though i understand what is the error, i cant seem to figure out any way to get around it, can someone help? 
here is a little code.

```
GivenQuestionsCache=LRUCache(maxsize=100,missing=getGivenQuestions)
now GivenQuestionsCache[1] gives
{1: [[211736, None], [211736, 'a'], [207113, 'a'], [219556, None], [207095, None], [89027, None], [89027, None]]}
```

and i am trying to do

```
GivenQuestionsCache[1].append([10,None])
```

then it throws that error. is there any other way to achieve this? 
i want my cache to become

```
{1: [[211736, None], [211736, 'a'], [207113, 'a'], [219556, None], [207095, None], [89027, None], [89027, None],[10,None]]}
```

Comment: Does "getGivenQuestions" return dict? If it is - then GivenQuestionsCache uses missing factory instead of this list.

Comment: yes it does return dict. sorry, what missing factory?

Comment: "missing" attribute is a factory that is used when you have cache miss
GivenQuestionsCache[a_key_does_not_exists] == getGivenQuestions()

Now you need to find out why is it no "1"  in your cache

Comment: Hi, but the key 1 is present in cache, like i showed in question 
'now GivenQuestionsCache[1] gives
{1: [[211736, None], [211736, 'a'], [207113, 'a'], [219556, None], [207095, None], [89027, None], [89027, None]]}'

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it works:

```
from cachetools import LRUCache
GivenQuestionsCache=LRUCache(maxsize=100,missing=lambda _: dict())
GivenQuestionsCache[1] = [[211736, None], [211736, 'a'], [207113, 'a'], [219556, None], [207095, None], [89027, None], [89027, None]]
GivenQuestionsCache[1].append([10,None])
print GivenQuestionsCache[1]
```

returns

```
[[211736, None],
 [211736, 'a'],
 [207113, 'a'],
 [219556, None],
 [207095, None],
 [89027, None],
 [89027, None],
 [10, None]]
```

But

`GivenQuestionsCache[2].append([10,None])`

will return

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

So you need to check all your code that potentially can modify GivenQuestionsCache.

Comment: it doesnt work for me, can you check if this works for python3+

Comment: print(GivenQuestionsCache.__contains__(studentId))
     GivenQuestionsCache.__getitem__(studentId).append([int(questionId),None])
i am doing this, first line prints true but i am getting error still, no one else is modifying the cache

Comment: hmm, tested in Python 3.4.3 and python 2.7.6 - had no problems

Comment: also what is yours python version and cachetools version

Comment: i am using pyhton 3+ also, my doubt is when i print GivenQuestionsCache[1] i get o/p like {1: [[211736, None], [211736, 'a'], [207113, 'a'], [219556, None], [207095, None], [89027, None], [89027, None]]} where when you print it only printed values, why is that?

Comment: Well, you are trying to pring GivenQuestionsCache[1], right?
so "1" is a dict key, and value is your list [[211736, ....]].
That's why my print returns list only.
Maybe you have some kind of nested dicts inside, like:
{1: {1: [[211736, ..]]}} ?